# Assembly code 8085 to separate odd number from a given list of number and store them into a new list

Tags: assembly, 8085

```
LXI H, 2200H
LXI D, 2300H
MVI C, 32H

BACK:    MOV A, M
               ANI 01H
              JNZ SKIP
              MOV A, M
              STAX D
              INX D
SKIP:    INX H
              DCR C
              JNZ BACK
               HLT
```

with these I only can find even number, not the odd number can anyone help to fix my code?

Comment: If you want to skip in the opposite situation that it's skipping now, change `JNZ SKIP` to `JZ SKIP`.

Comment: It fixes already, ok thank bro for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the `JNZ` to `JZ` in 7th line.
Here is the modified code:

```
LXI H, 2200H
LXI D, 2300H
MVI C, 32H

BACK: MOV A, M
    ANI 01H
    JZ SKIP #JNZ changed to JZ
    MOV A, M
    STAX D
    INX D

SKIP: INX H
    DCR C
    JNZ BACK

HLT
```